# Swift: Create like and comment buttons like the Facebook and Twitter iOS apps

Tags: swift, uibutton

Working on a  social networking iPhone app written in `Swift` and I'm trying to figure out how to create a like button and a comment button similar to the ones on the Facebook and Twitter iOS apps.

For example, for my current like button, I have a `UIButton` with a smiling emoticon as the image of the `UIButton` inside the prototype `Cell`. Just to the right of this button, I have a `UILabel` with the text "Like" (indicating that the smiling emoticon to the left is a like button).

How can one create a button that has the icon and the text together as one button so that the user can tap either on the Like icon part or the "Like" text part of the button which makes it easier for the user to tap the like button?

```
Screenshot: Facebook buttons example
```

[image: Facebook buttons example]

```
Screenshot : Twitter buttons example
```

[image: Twitter buttons example]

I took a screenshot of the Twitter buttons when my finger was pressing the like button. Notice how the like button here is greyed out (both the heart icon part and the number of likes). This is the effect I would like.

I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'll only give you a basic idea of how to do this because your question is broad and did not show what you have tried.

Basically, create a `UIButton` subclass. Let's call it `SocialButton`.

Override the `drawRect` method in the `SocialButton` class. In the method, you should use `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` to get a `CGContext`. Then call `CGContextDrawImage` to draw the image in a `CGRect`. This `CGRect` is the position that your image will go.

Here's some code to give you an idea:

```
class SocialButton: UIButton {
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextDrawImage(context, someRect, UIImage(named: "someImage")?.CGImage)
    }
}
```

`someRect` is the rectangle that the image will be drawn in.

EDIT:

To add a social button to the storyboard, you need to add `@IBDesignable` on top of your class. And I think you should also add a property called `image`. This way people can set what image they want in the button. So now the class will look like this:

```
@IBDesignable
class SocialButton: UIButton {
    @IBInspectable // This is added so that you can change the image in interface builder
    var image: UIImage?

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        CGContextDrawImage(context, someRect, self.image?.CGImage)
        // You can also set the tint, bg color and other stuff here.
    }
}
```

Now that's all you have to change in your class. On to the storyboard!

First, drag a `UIButton` to the view controller and select it:

[image]

Then, open the identity inspector on the right. If you don't know what it is, just click the ID card icon on the left side of Xcode.

[image]

Do you see that "Class" field? Just type "SocialButton" in there and press enter:

[image]

Switch to the property inspector(The one with a slider icon), you should see your custom button's image property:

[image]

You can select an image using the property inspector and if you have implemented `drawRect` correctly, you should see your image drawn on the left of the button now.

Comment: I explained how I have a `UIButton` with a smiling emoticon image as the image of the `UIButton` inside the prototype cell of my Storyboard. I'm not sure how to apply your programmatic approach to place the programmatic button in place of the storyboard button...

Comment: @DiligentDev I edited my answer to show you how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe also use [Font Awesome](https://github.com/Vaberer/Font-Awesome-Swift) to add custom icon then a text to a `UIBUtton` .

For example you can use :

```
buttonName.setFAText(prefixText: "follow me on ", icon: FAType.FATwitter, postfixText: ". Thanks!", size: 25, forState: .Normal, iconSize: 30)
```

to have your label and a twitter icon.

Hope this will help you !